# Unable to control Starting of BeaconService

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

Using altbeacon library. I am not able to control beacon service startup. I have checked many points but still BeaconService is starting up. With the conditions in place the BeaconService should not startup. Does creating a BeaconManager automatically starts the BeaconService? Are there any other points that I should check for?

Answer (score 0):

The 2.0.x releases of the library *do* start up automatically when the phone reboots or when power is connected or disconnected, and there isn't an easy way to stop it.  This has been changed in the 2.1 version of the library (available for download in beta) so that it will not start up automatically unless you construct the `RegionBootstrap` class in a custom `Application` class.

You can read more detail about the root cause of this issue [here.](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/42)

If you want to keep using the 2.0.x release, there is a workaround described in that link.